# send mail using php using xampp

Tags: php, email, xampp

I can't send mail,can anyone help with it?I tried to surf google but I still got no answer.
I am  using the application called XAMPP, does itmay be the cause of it? Does XAMPP have all php functionalities?

this is mailform.php

```
<?php 
$to = "ratisharabidze@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Test mail"; 
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message."; 
$from = "ratisharabidze@yahoo.com"; 
$headers = "From: $from"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
echo "Mail Sent."; 
?>
```

this is a form.html

```
<html> 
<body> 
<?php 
function spamcheck($field) 
{ 
    //eregi() performs a case insensitive regular expression match 
    if(eregi("to:",$field) || eregi("cc:",$field)) 
    { 
        return TRUE; 
    } else 
    { 
        return FALSE; 
    } 
} //if "email" is filled out, send email 

if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) 
{ 
    //check if the email address is invalid 
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']); 
    if ($mailcheck==TRUE) 
    { 
        echo "Invalid input";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        //send email 
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ; 
        $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ; 
        mail("someone@example.com", "Subject: $subject", $message, "From: $email" ); 
        echo "Thank you for using our mail form"; 
    } 
} 
else 
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form 
{ 
    echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'> 
    Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br /> 
    Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br /> 
    Message:<br /> <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'> </textarea><br /> 
    <input type='submit' /> 
    </form>";
?> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you turned on apache on your xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new, the easiest way is to use the free `gmail SMTP server`.

Edit your `php.ini` in `XAMPP` (In control panel, click `config` button next to `apache` and select `php.ini`).

In that file find the line below. Uncomment the `sendmail_path` by removing the `semi-colon` from the beginning of the line.

`;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Next configure your `sendmail settings` for gmail:

`smtp_server` should be mail.gmail.com.`auth_username` and `auth_password` will be your gmail username and password. `smtp_port` should be 465.

Restart XAMPP and if everything is fine, you should be good to go.

Comment: what I must do exactly? I am new to php

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at PHPMailer; much better than the PHP Mail() Function :)

Comment: Thank you! I used to be part of the team that built PHPMailer! :)